# IgniteRDD Spark

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

Is it possible to read data from an IgniteRdd inside a .map() function of a Spark RDD? I am trying to do this using the following code and it doesnt give me any errors but just endless logs:

```
19/11/13 19:20:28 INFO IgniteKernal: 
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=3058da95, uptime=00:01:00.014]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=1, CPUs=4]
    ^-- CPU [cur=0.5%, avg=2.81%, GC=0%]
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=6893]
    ^-- Heap [used=160MB, free=95.45%, comm=417MB]
    ^-- Non heap [used=83MB, free=-1%, comm=85MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=6, qSize=0]
19/11/13 19:20:28 INFO IgniteKernal: FreeList [name=null, buckets=256, dataPages=247, reusePages=0]
```

The code I am using (might contain errors but the idea is on the usage of IgniteRDD inside map function) :

```
    object test extends App {
    // Spark Configuration.
    private val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("IgniteRDDExample")
        .setMaster("local")
        .set("spark.executor.instances", "2")

    // Spark context.
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)

    // Defines spring cache Configuration path.
    private val CONFIG = "examples/config/spark/example-shared-rdd.xml"

    // Creates Ignite context with above configuration.
    val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sparkContext, CONFIG, false)
    val word2ID: IgniteRDD[String, Int] = igniteContext.fromCache[String, Int]("sharedRDD")
    word2ID.savePairs(sparkContext.textFile("word2id.txt").map(i =>{
      var res:Array[String]= i.split("\t")
      (res(0), Integer.valueOf(res(1)))
      }))

     val file = sparkContext.textFile("sentence.txt") // a file with 5 columns of strings 
     val words = file.map(i =>{
     val res:Array[String]= i.split("\t")
     (res(0), res(1), res(2), res(3), res(4))
     })

     val ids: IgniteRDD[Long, word] = igniteContext.fromCache[Long, word]("TriplesId")

     val word_id = words.map(j => {

       val w1 = word2ID.filter(_._1.equals(j._1)).first()
       val w2 = word2ID.filter(_._1.equals(j._2)).first()
       val w3 = word2ID.filter(_._1.equals(j._3)).first()
       val w4 = word2ID.filter(_._1.equals(j._4)).first()
       val w5 = word2ID.filter(_._1.equals(j._5)).first()

      word(w1._2,w2._2,w3._2,w4._2,w5._2)
      })

      case class word(w1:Int, w2:Int, w3:Int, w4:Int, w5:Int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you see current issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-11724

It marked as won't fix because it's hard to predict what kinds of exceptions Spark can have in user functions.

Try to add try/cache blocks around your method that executes your map function.

This exception will provide the details of what was wrong in your code.

Also please note that Ignite node started in your Spark job will be stopped only when you close IgniteContext or current spark session.

Comment: The problem is that there is no exception, the program just stalls and keeps printing the node metrics logs. My question is  'is it possible to read the igniterdd inside of a map function of a sparkrdd', or how can I access the igniteRDD (the shared cache) inside workers (when I do a map)?

Comment: Okay, I thought that your problem was related to handling of the IgniteContext. According to your question - you can't create the RDD inside map functions of another RDD. And as I mentioned before you should close igniteContext. It will help you to stop Ignite client started in your job.